# Run cleanup code after exception has occured (Java/Cucumber)

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a cucumber method that does some cleanup after tests are finished.

```
@After("@First")
public void resetUsers() throws BankServiceException_Exception {
    bank.retireAccount(customerBankID);
    bank.retireAccount(merchantBankID);
}
```

This method is however not run in case one of the tests throw an exception and then the cleanup will not happen.

Is there a way to make the cleanup logic happen at all times? Even after an exception has occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@After("@First") -Its a tagged hook,i.e. this hook will run only after those scenarios which are having tags @First ,if you want to execute a method which should be run after each scenario ,use hooks without any tag as given below-

@After
public void resetUsers() throws BankServiceException_Exception {
    bank.retireAccount(customerBankID);
    bank.retireAccount(merchantBankID);
}
```